# Get “Illegal generic type for instanceof” error when coparison

Tags: java, android

In my code there are 3 custom classes

```
CheckinTemplate
Employee
Status
```

While there was one scenario came that an `Object o`, can be possibly any of above class's list. And I want to compare as follow and do certain logic but an error came "Illegal generic type for instanceof"

```
if (o instanceof List<CheckinTemplate>) {

} else if (o instanceof List<Employee>) {

} else if (o instanceof List<Status>) {

}
```

Comment: Is `o` a `List`?

Comment: Java cannot distinguish these types due to type erasure.

Comment: o is declared as Object, but initialized as any of the list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can't be done, since `instanceof` is evaluated in runtime, but generic type parameters are erased during compilation. This means that in runtime there is no difference between `List<CheckinTemplate>` and `List<Employee>`.

You can check whether `o instanceof List` (or `o instanceof List<?>` if you want to avoid using a raw `List` type). If it is, you can cast it to `List` (or `List<?>`) and then run `instanceof` on its elements to determine their type.

```
if (o instanceof List) {
    List list = (List) o;
    for (Object e : list) {
        if (e instanceof CheckinTemplate) {

        } else if (e instanceof Employee) {

        } else if (e instanceof Status) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `List<?> list= (List<?>) o` if you want to suppress warning of rawtypes.

Answer (score 1):

Java Language Specification states:

[15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> is a compile-time error if the ReferenceType mentioned after the instanceof operator does not denote a reference type that is reifiable (§4.7)

and [4.7. Reifiable Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)

> ...
>
> A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:
>
> - It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration
> - **It is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards**
> - It is a raw type
> - ...

This is understandable because of [4.6. Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6), that is, at compile time type information is *lost* and not put into the compiled class file. At runtime there is no type information available to the virtual machine to check what type the List is, so it cannot be checked by `instanceof`.

Comment: Prior to Java SE 16, the ReferenceType operand of a type comparison operator was required to be reifiable (§4.7). This prevented the use of a parameterized type unless all its type arguments were wildcards. The requirement was lifted in Java SE 16 to allow more parameterized types to be used. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to do that one you check class name of the object and compare it with string

```
if(o.getClass.toString().equals("myClass")){
}
```

second you can check instance of the class like this!

```
if (object instanceof MyClass) {

}
```

What you are doing you trying (`o instanceof List<CheckinTemplate>` that is wrong do it like `array.get(x)` or `object instanceof CheckinTemplate` in If condition!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use generic types in `instanceof` i.e. you can do `o instanceof List` but not `o instanceof List<Status>`. This is because Java erases generic type information at compile time.

Of course, there is a hack you might be able to use. If you are sure that the list is non-empty and homogeneous  (all items in the list are the same type and not null), then instead of checking the list type, check the type of one of its items.

```
Object item = o.get(0);
if (item instanceof CheckinTemplate) {
} else if (item instanceof Employee) {
} else if (item instanceof Status) {
}
```